# Google places place.open_now

Tags: javascript, css, function, google-maps, google-places-api

Here I have a script that show me a opening hours for object with google places api.
http://jsbin.com/ATaZEXE/4

Now I want to change background color on .label class to "red" if place.open_now is false if, true then must stay the same

How I can do that?

With this code I check opening_hours for object but how to change color if place.open_now is false ?

```
(function(marker,request,i){
        setTimeout(function(){
         service.getDetails(request, function(place, status){
          try{
            var time=place.opening_hours.periods[1].open.time;
            var closed=place.opening_hours.periods[1].close.time;
            var closed=[(closed/100).toFixed(0),closed.substr(-2)].join(':');
            marker.set('labelContent',[(time/100).toFixed(0),time.substr(-2)].join(':')+' - '+closed+'</br>'+place.name);
          }
          catch(e){}
         });
        },
        i*250)
      })(marker,request,i);
```

where I need to add `IF` statement to check is place.open_now true or false and how to change background if `place.open_now` is false?

*from google places api documentation:
opening_hours may contain the following information:
open_now is a boolean value indicating if the Place is open at the current time.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this css

```
.labels.closed {
  background-color: red;
}
```

and this javascript

```
var isClosed = true; // find out it's closed or not
marker.set('labelClass', isClosed ? "labels closed" : "labels");
```

Comment: yes but please update my jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ATaZEXE/4 where I need to put this css nad js code?

Comment: sorry i only use plnkr.co, http://jsbin.com/ATaZEXE/7/edit. You need to complete your code to find out if it is closed or not. I just made an sample.

Comment: thanks but I try: var isClosed = place.open_now;
            if isClosed = true; // find out it's closed or not
marker.set('labelClass', isClosed ? "labels closed" : "labels");, but dont work well